# Meaning of Surrogate Split

Tags: regression, machine-learning, data-mining, random-forest, boosting

I tried to figure but couldn't on what happens when missing values are present in some predictor variable and we have to solve the problem of regression using Random Forest. What is the meaning of surrogate split to handle that?

It will be good if a snapshot of the working of algorithm in that part of missing data could be shown.

Comment: hello you have an excellent answer below - maybe click on that green button over there to award?

Answer (score 23):

Surrogate splits are referenced elsewhere on this site, but I don't find an explanation for what they are. E.g.:

[how does rpart handle missing values in predictors?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50310/how-does-rpart-handle-missing-values-in-predictors/108442#108442)

[How do decision tree learning algorithms deal with missing values (under the hood)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96025/how-do-decision-tree-learning-algorithms-deal-with-missing-values-under-the-hoo/96458#96458)

I use the [documentation to rpart](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf) and these [lecture notes](https://www.ismll.uni-hildesheim.de/lehre/ml-09w/script/ml-04-decisiontrees-2up.pdf) to give an example of a surrogate split. I construct an example using `rpart` in `R`:

```
tmp_df <- 
    data.frame(Y = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
               weight = 10:1,
               height = c(10:7, 5, 6, 4:1))

tmp_df$weight[3] <- NA
```

This generates the following data frame:

```
   Y weight height
1  1     10     10
2  1      9      9
3  1      8      8
4  1      7      7
5  1      6      5
6  0      5      6
7  0     NA      4
8  0      3      3
9  0      2      2
10 0      1      1
```

It is clear through the intent of the construction that the cutpoint `weight > 5.5` gives a perfect split for the categorical response `Y` if the `weight` variable has no missing values.

Now, an algorithm that ignores missing values will just discard row 7, and still obtain a split equivalent to `weight > 5.5`. The package `rpart` does not do this, it instead computes a **surrogate split** on the height variable, `height > 3.5`.

The idea behind this is as follows: `Weight` is obviously the best variable to split on. However, when `Weight` is missing, a split using `Height` is a good approximation to the split otherwise obtained using `Weight`.

Let's fit two models to demonstrate this, first, `tm_0`, a normal tree model with no surrogates, and `tm` a tree model using the default surrogate behaviour in `rpart`:

```
tm_0 <- rpart(Y ~ weight + height, data = tmp_df, 
              control = rpart.control(minsplit = 1,
                                      minbucket=1, 
                                      cp=0, 
                                      maxdepth = 1, 
                                      usesurrogate = 0))

tm <- rpart(Y ~ weight + height, data = tmp_df, 
            control = rpart.control(minsplit =1,
                                    minbucket=1, 
                                    cp=0, 
                                    maxdepth = 1))
```

We see that the splits are as I describe, from `summary(tm)`:

```
  Primary splits:
      weight < 5.5 to the left,  improve=4.444444, (1 missing)
      height < 4.5 to the left,  improve=3.333333, (0 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      height < 3.5 to the left,  agree=0.889, adj=0.75, (1 split)
```

Now, compare the predictions from these two models using the following new data:

```
tmp_new_df <- data.frame(weight = c(rep(NA_real_, 4), 3:6), height = rep(3:6, 2))
> tmp_new_df
  weight height
1     NA      3
2     NA      4
3     NA      5
4     NA      6
5      3      3
6      4      4
7      5      5
8      6      6
```

Contrast `predict(tm_0, newdata = tmp_new_df)` (first column is probability of being in class `0`):

```
    0   1
1 0.5 0.5
2 0.5 0.5
3 0.5 0.5
4 0.5 0.5
5 1.0 0.0
6 1.0 0.0
7 1.0 0.0
8 0.0 1.0
```

to `predict(tm, newdata = tmp_new_df)`:

```
          0         1
1 1.0000000 0.0000000
2 0.1666667 0.8333333
3 0.1666667 0.8333333
4 0.1666667 0.8333333
5 1.0000000 0.0000000
6 1.0000000 0.0000000
7 1.0000000 0.0000000
8 0.1666667 0.8333333
```

In the first four rows, since `weight` has missing values, the decision tree `tm_0` is unable to make a prediction using the split on `weight`, so returns the class membership ratio at the root node. In contrast, the tree `tm` using surrogate splits is able to use the `height` variable to give a more accurate prediction for these rows. However, note the difference in the latter four rows. The tree with surrogate splits is unable to give a 'perfect' prediction due to how observations with missing values in the predictors are aggregated in the terminal nodes. (See the documentation to rpart for more details).

Comment: excellent example thx.

Comment: I wish all explanations about trees were like this! Well done!

Comment: Apparently, in the newer versions of rpart, they chantes something and the predictions I have in the second case are (giving only the "1"-column) 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1.

Comment: Question: what would happen if the primary- and surrogate-variable are missing? (in my case, apparently, some kind of average is computed), however, I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it has been more than two years since I've looked at this so I cannot answer your question. Perhaps you are better asking a new question tied specifically to the version of rpart you are referring to... with examples.

Comment: @Antoine, I am also very much interested in your question. Judging by the usage of surrogates there will be no averages computed. If there is no surrogate, then algorithm will fail. This is my guess only. I might be wrong.